# Возможно ли узнать индекс выбранной строки в TPopupMenu?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Как узнать индекс выбранной строки в TPopupMenu?

Comment: строки или пункта меню?

Как быстрый хак, который точно будет работать, могу предложить свойство tag. При создании элемента туда записываются нужные числа, когда нужно, кодом легко достаются.

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь - tag всегда равен 0, пока в него не впишешь что-нибудь сам.

Comment: я же и пишу - туда вписывайте все что нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вывод в `Memo1` текста выделенного пункта меню:

**Popup**
свойство **OwnerDraw = True**

для всех пунктов меню **Popup**, тип **TMenuItem**
событие **OnDrawItem = MenuItemDrawItem**

Код события:

```
procedure [название формы].MenuItemDrawItem(Sender: TObject; ACanvas: TCanvas; ARect: TRect; Selected: Boolean);
var
  MI: TMenuItem;
  State: TOwnerDrawState;
begin
  MI := TMenuItem(Sender);
  MI.OnDrawItem := nil;
  if Selected then
    State := [odSelected]
  else
    State := [];
  DrawMenuItem(MI, ACanvas, ARect, State);
  MI.OnDrawItem := MenuItemDrawItem;
  if (Sender is TMenuItem) then
    Memo1.Lines.Add((Sender as TMenuItem).Caption); //для проверки
end;
```

Comment: @NMD Здорово! Мне на ум тоже один способ в голову пришел, хочу поделиться, но понятия не имею как вставить в этот чат код так, чтобы он в строку не переформировался. Подскажешь как это сделать?

Comment: чтобы что?

Comment: Чтобы он в одну строку не собрался. Типа: begin label1.caption:='Привет Мир!' end;

Comment: мда. понятно стало вообще

Comment: procedure [название формы].MenuItemDrawItem(Sender: TObject; ACanvas: TCanvas; ARect: TRect; Selected: Boolean);
var
  MI: TMenuItem;
  State: TOwnerDrawState;
begin
  MI := TMenuItem(Sender);
  MI.OnDrawItem := nil;
  if Selected then begin
    State := [odSelected];
  end
  else State := [];
  DrawMenuItem(MI,ACanvas,ARect,State);
  MI.OnDrawItem:=MenuItemDrawItem;
  if (Sender is TMenuItem) then
  begin
    Memo1.Lines.Add( (Sender as TMenuItem).Caption ) ; //для проверки
  end;
end;

Comment: не понял что вообще надо

Comment: @АлександрЪ
В форме для ввода ответа есть кнопочка для кода `{}`.
Какую задачу вы пытаетесь решить получая индекс выбранной строки в PopupMenu? Может эту задачу нужно решать по другому?

Comment: словами напишите, что нужно и все!